# Regualr Expression for 10 digit number starting with 65 in a string

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I am trying to write regular expression that can handle following cases :-

```
1.6512345678
2. I am 6512345678 new.
3. \s6512345678
4. I am 6512345678\n
5. 6512345678 is here.
```

It only works for case 1, 3 and 5.
If the number is at the beginning it is working but when it is in between or at the end it is not.
What changes I should make to match all the cases?

This is my regular expression `(?<!\d)^\s?65\d{8}\s?(?!\d)`

Comment: `^65[0-9]{8}$` ?

Comment: Actually I had to use `(?<=\D|^)65[0-9]{8}(?=\D|$)` to cover all your edge cases, [see the demo](https://regex101.com/r/Y4YpDv/1).

Comment: Thanks @TimBiegeleisen, it works for all the cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
(^|[^\d])65\d{8}[^\d]
```

which says, either its starts with the beginning, or not a digit followed by 65 then 8 digit, followed by not a digit

Comment: You're missing an `$` anchor at the end of your pattern, see my comments above

Comment: With an $ anchor at the end, it works for all the cases.